# Phone and backend connection, how to minimize hacking

Tags: ssl, afnetworking

I was reading some topics about security and how hackers can look at the request you send to the backend to figure out how your system works but I did not find any good solution to avoid this.

So I was wondering what would you do in your app (here an iphone app) to make sure that hackers cannot see the content of the request your sending to the backend.

example http://myserver.com/api.php/login&pwd=test&username=pwd,

how to hide this so that no one can see the content.

I was thinking of different solutions:

1) encrypt the pwd and the username (not ideal as hacker can still see the post function of the server you are sending the request to)

2) use SSL request (I think this is only interesting to secure the connection to the server, meaning if the hacker is using his phone to connect to the server he should be able to see the request he is sending and so see the full URL)

3) change my backend so that all the request are sent to the same post function with an encrypted message. Finally the backend would decrypt and dispatch the message to the right function. This could work as the hacker would only see the url I am sending my request but would not have any information on what I am sending.

example: http://myserver.com/api.php/receiver&message=415gre6168sg4rg4e61g6r8g

"415gre6168sg4rg4e61g6r8g" could be decrypted as:
"login#pwd#username" and so I would be able to send this to the right function

But I am sure some of you have encounter similar issues and have better suggestions, would be interested to see what you would do,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any encryption you add is an extra effort for the hackers.

But in terms of what concerns to Apple use SSL connection should be enought based on [iOS and the new IT - Security](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/security.html).

You can read more about the security polices used/recommended by Apple on [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf)